# Objective-c simple memory question

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management

If I have a variable in my view controler

viewcontroller.m

```
@interface MemoryTestViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *array;
}

@end
```

in my implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *aux = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    array = aux;
    [aux release];
    // Do i have to do array release?
}
```

Do i have to release my variable array somewhere? Theoricaly i havent allocated that variable...
I testes the memory leaks and even if i dont release anything the instruments doesn't detect any leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to release. All you do is assign the pointer of `aux` to your `array` variable.
`array` is invalid at the moment where you release `aux`.
This is probably not as intended. If you want to work with `array`, you'll have to retain it.

Comment: What happens if i have something like NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]...] and then i do again name = [[NSString alloc]...] Do i have to release it before allocating again?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you would allocate memory for the first string but overwrite your reference to the block of allocated memory. Hence you would not be able to release it later. You should Google for "ios memory management" and read Apple's guides. Things will get simpler with iOS5 which has automatic reference counting.

Comment: Could I do something like [name initWithString:...] after the first alloc?

Comment: Yes, but you'll leak memory as the first string won't get released.
You have to learn the basics like "only release what you own". 
Read into the memory management guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1

Comment: @Marc: NO! You cannot (well, [should not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752672/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-call-init-outside-of-alloc-init)) re-initialize an instance /cc `@`Krumelur

Comment: It's always difficult to answer questions with "can I". Of course you can. The compiler will not complain. But will it behave as you expect it to do is a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

You've already released the array with `[aux release];` -- you in fact have the opposite problem to a leak: an over-release.

Assignments in Objective-C are just assignments of pointers; there's no copying or automatic [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html). When you say `array = aux;`, `array` now points to the exact same object as `aux`. If you then get rid of `aux` by releasing it (and therefore letting it be deallocated), `array` doesn't point to anything anymore.*

You have a couple of options for fixing this:

1. (Simplest) Assign the newly-created array directly to `array`:

   ```
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
   ```

   This gives you ownership of the new array, under the name `array`. Don't release it until you are done with it (possibly in `dealloc`; certainly not in this method).
2. (Best) Create a [declared property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) for `array` and let that mechanism handle the memory management for you:

```
@interface MemoryTestViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *array;  
}  

@property (copy, nonatomic, setter=setArrayByMutableCopy) NSMutableArray * array;
@end

@implementation MemoryTestViewController
@synthesize array;

// Properties can't automatically make mutable copies, so you need to create
// your own setter method.
- (void) setArrayByMutableCopy: (NSMutableArray *)newArray {
    NSMutableArray * tmp = [newArray mutableCopy];
    [array release];
    array = tmp;
}
...
```

*Or, rather, it points to a place where there used to be a valid object, which is a great way to make your program crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a property:

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;

and later in your viewDidLoad:

// wrong, leaks: self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

and yes, somewhat later release it, probably in dealloc..

Comment: This statement `self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];` leaks. It should be `self.array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1] autorelease];`. The autorelease balances the alloc-init, and the property setter retains the object, which is balanced by the corresponding release in dealloc.

Comment: I wrote "... later release it".

Comment: Doing it that way, you don't have a reference through which you _can_ release it later (strictly speaking, it's possible to `[self.array release]` right after this, but that is a really terrible code smell. You should generally have one pointer per retain -- IOW, one _reference_ for every _reference count_. /cc @albertamg

Answer (score 0):

No. Assigning an object to a variable does not retain it. However if you plan to use that variable for a while, you should retain it and release it when you are done with it.

`alloc` raised the retain counter to *1* and `[aux release]` set it to *0*

Comment: `alloc` gives the object a retain count of 1, _not_ `init...`