# Re-initializing an object

Tags: objective-c, object, initialization

I have an object with a bunch of custom properties which I set up in the `init` method. At some point I'd like to reset the object to it's original state. It's stated in Apple's documentation that `init` should never be called separate from `alloc`, so using ARC, this seems to me to be a perfectly reasonable way to do it to me:

```
MyObject* myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init]; // inits myStringProperty to @""
myObject.myStringProperty = @"Hello world!";
NSLog(myObject.myStringProperty);

myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init]; // resets myStringProperty back to @""
NSLog(myObject.myStringProperty);
```

However, I've read (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752672/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-call-init-outside-of-alloc-init/2754495#2754495)) that a common pattern in this case is to explicitly define a `reset` method and refactor the re-initialisation code to there. Obviously this avoids having to create a whole new object (although I can't imagine the overhead of this is so high and leaving the release and re-allocation to ARC seems to be the simplest way) but is there any other reason for preferring one method over another? What is the general Objective C pattern for object re-initialization?

Comment: No, the `reset` method is the way I'd go.

Comment: yup, but this is the purpose of my question – why?

Comment: For example, in C++ it is a common pattern to reinitialize an object by recreating it, but then C++ is far more philosophically tied to the idea of freely making fresh copies of objects (e.g. the STL containers) so appreciate that objective c may be different

Comment: Conversely, there are plenty of convenience factory methods (e.g. [NSNumber numberWithInt:]) which will basically be doing this behind the scenes, so recreating doesn't seem to be completely unknown in Objective-C world

Comment: `NSNumber` is a special case. It's worth learning from, but few classes look quite like it. First, it's a class cluster. Second, it includes caching (if you call `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` several times, you'll keep getting the same object).

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for your comments Rob, I didn't know that about the caching in the NSNumber convenience factory methods, and your point about immutability also provides some food for thought!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your primary purpose in creating a `reset` method is to avoid the overhead of releasing and allocating a new object, then I would say skip the reset method in most cases.  Unless initializing your object is very complicated or time-consuming, this is a useless micro-optimization.  Keep your class (and the code that uses it) simpler and just create a new object when you need a new object.

The only example I can think of for an Objective-C class that is reused is a `UITableViewCell`.  There is a good reason to make these reusable, since it avoids degrading scrolling performance.

Comment: Also, when the number of objects you create is high, e.g. several thousands, then reusing might be a good idea to avoid too many allocations and deallocations.

Comment: One more reason for not using `reset` if you don't need it: there are many advantages to value (immutable) objects. `reset` prevents you from doing that.

Comment: Perfect! I suspected as much, and my natural inclination was to just allocate a new object, but then found many people on SO describing adding a `reset` method to fulfil the same purpose so wondered whether there was some reason why this might be preferred. It's comforting to know that this isn't the case, and running with just a fresh `[[Object alloc] init]` is indeed a regular pattern in Obj-C.